# Getting horizontally the longest same element sequence

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2d Arraylist (2d Arraylist, `myBoard` works well and was tested multiple times for correctness) and would like to return the longest sequence of the same elements in a list. If I call `myBoard.toString()`, the output looks like this:

```
   |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
-2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
-1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 1 |  A|  A|  A|   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 6 |  B|  B|  B|  B|  B|  B|   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 7 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 8 |  C|  C|  D|  C|  C|  C|  C|  C|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 9 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I'm aware that the Arraylists start from 0 and have a couple of other methods that handle that case. But my concern is my code isnt working to get the longest sequence from the board horizontally. The longest sequence is in `row 6` but it returns `[(0,1,), (0,1,), (0,2,), (0,2,), (0,5,), (0,5,), (0,6,), (0,6,), (0,7,), (0,7,)]`. Why is it returning [(0,1,), (0,1,), (0,2,), (0,2,), (0,5,), (0,5,), (0,6,), (0,6,), (0,7,), (0,7,)]??

```
     public List<RowAndCol<T>> horizontalSequence(){
         ArrayList<RowAndCol<T>> myList = new ArrayList<RowAndCol<T>>();
         int max = 1;
         int currentCount = 1;

         for(int i = 0; i < myBoard.size(); i++){
             for(int j = 1; j < myBoard.get(i).size(); j++){
                 if(myBoard.get(j - 1).equals(myBoard.get(j))){
                     RowAndCol<T> tempObject1 = new RowAndCol<T>(i, j, myBoard.get(i).get(j));
                     RowAndCol<T> tempObject2 = new RowAndCol<T>(i, j-1, myBoard.get(i).get(j-1));
                     myList.add(tempObject1);
                     myList.add(tempObject2);
                     currentCount++;
                 }
                 else{
                     if(currentCount > max){
                         if(currentCount > myList.size()){
                             max = currentCount;
                         }
                         currentCount = 1;
                     }

                 }
             }
return myList;
         }
```

`RowAndCol` class has only a constructor that accepts `(int row, int col, T e)`, `getters` and `toString()` method

```
  public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        if(this.e instanceof String){
            String element = (String)this.e;
            result = "(" + this.row + "," + this.col + "," + element + ")";
        }
        else if(this.e instanceof Integer){
            Integer element = (Integer)this.e;
            result = "(" + this.row + "," + this.col + "," + element + ")";
        }
        else if(this.e instanceof Character){
            Character element = (Character)this.e;
            result = "(" + this.row + "," + this.col + "," + element + ")";
        }
        return result;
        }
```

Comment: tempObject1 and tempObject2 are the same object. That's you have the same element twice into the list. Why would you put two times the same element?

Comment: @TheCodingMonk, I changed it, but still gives me the same result that I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of the `else`:

```
if(myBoard.get(j - 1).equals(myBoard.get(j))){
    RowAndCol<T> tempObject1 = new RowAndCol<T>(i, j, myBoard.get(i).get(j));
    RowAndCol<T> tempObject2 = new RowAndCol<T>(i, j-1, myBoard.get(i).get(j-1));
    myList.add(tempObject1);
    myList.add(tempObject2);
    currentCount++;
}

    if(currentCount > max){
            myList.clear() // Reset the list to get rid of the old elements
            max = currentCount;
        currentCount = 1;

}
```

Comment: Same result :( @TheCodingMonk

Comment: See the edit. You're testing for `currentCount > myList.size()` but that condition is never true.